# how to get the JSON code of a .ipynb file?

Tags: python, json, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I have a problem when I try to open an Ipynb file in Jupyter lab, I get this error :

`Unreadable notebook [...] NotJSONError("Notebook does not appear to be JSON: ''...")`

I get this error even if I create the file with Jupyter lab directly
I already tried to update Jupyter and to update Nodejs but nothing change.
Before I had this problem I didn't even know that ipynb files were made with JSON so I am a bit lost.

does anyone know how I can get the JSON code of my Ipynb file?

Comment: You can open it in any text editor, like Sublime, PyCharm, VS code, Notepad, Emacs, Vim, whatever, and see what's missing.  Maybe you inadvertently edited the file, and probably one of the closing parentheses got deleted.

Comment: it doesn't work with vscode because it automatically show the code cells to edit them just like in jupyter lab, but it worked with emacs. thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can validate the .ipynb file with a JSON validator: [like this one](https://www.freeformatter.com/json-validator.html)

Comment: hi ! now that i got the JSON code i can see that it is empty, so the problem is obvious, but now I'd like to know why when i create a ipynb file in jupyter lab it doesn't automatically make it usable on jupyter lab ?